# SharePoint 2013 close modal image link

Tags: javascript, navigation, modal-dialog, popup

On the screenshot below I have circled a 'home' image button on the modal dialog page. I would somehow like to add a close window function to this to close the modal dialog.

I have tried the below code however this does not appear to work within the modal.

Any ideas?

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="120" height="24" onclick="window.close();">
```

[image: Modal Close Windows]

Comment: <img src="image.jpg" width="120" height="24" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();"/> 

try this. Assuming this is a SharePoint modal popup

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="120" height="24" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();"/>
```

OR

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="120" height="24" onclick="window.frameElement.commitPopup();">
```

**SP Dialog framework** extends the **window.frameElement** object, So you can use either of this.